# Not able to fetch proper postgres data from database pod

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, graphql, psycopg2

I've create a Graphql API with Flask framework deployed with uWSGI in Kubernetes cluster to fetch data from postgres database.

Connector postgres file with psycopg2 package creating a threaded connection pool:

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import pool
import psycopg2.extras

try:
    conn = pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(4, 8, 
                                       user='admin',
                                       password='password',
                                       host='100.66.19.56',
                                       database='db',
                                       cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    ps_conn = conn.getconn()
    ps_conn.autocommit = True

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print("Error in PostgreSQL Connection", error)
```

Resolver for graphql API to fetch app details:

```py
import database.conn as pc
from graphql import GraphQLError

class FetchAppDataResolver:

    def resolve_FetchAppData(self, parent, info):
        res = []
        try:
            cursor1 = pc.ps_conn.cursor()
            cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM db_schema.app_table;")
            app_details = cursor1.fetchall()
            cursor1.close()
            res.append({"status_msg": "Successful", "app_details": app_details})
            
        except(Exception, GraphQLError) as e:
            print("Error: ", str(e))
            pc.ps_conn.rollback()
            res.append({"status_msg": "Error", "app_details": []})
        return res
```

And another resolver to fetch category details with different cursor:

```
import database.conn as pc
from graphql import GraphQLError

class FetchCatDataResolver:

    def resolve_FetchCatData(self, parent, info):
        res = []
        try:
            cursor2 = pc.ps_conn.cursor()
            cursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM db_schema.cat_table;")
            cat_details = cursor2.fetchall()
            cursor2.close()
            res.append({"status_msg": "Successful", "cat_details": cat_details})
            
        except(Exception, GraphQLError) as e:
            print("Error: ", str(e))
            pc.ps_conn.rollback()
            res.append({"status_msg": "Error", "cat_details": []})
        return res
```

Multiple queries are hit from UI at the same time to the postgres database pod by creating different cursors for each resolver.

- Mostly, I'm getting proper data for all the different queries in UI
  but in some random cases the data in response schema are getting
  interchanged with each other.
- In few random cases the data are not
  properly fetched and provided with some null values sometimes.

Output with given resolver:

```
{
  "data": {
    "FetchAppDetails": [
      {
        "statusMsg": "Successful",
        "appDetails": [
          {
            "aId": null,
            "typeApp": null,
            "title": "Category1",
            "subTitle": null,
            "description": "Category1 desc"
          },
          {
            "aId": null,
            "typeApp": null,
            "title": "Category2",
            "subTitle": null,
            "description": "Category2 desc"
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Another output with different resolver to fetch data from different table:

```
{
  "data": {
    "FetchCatDetails": [
      {
        "statusMsg": "Successful",
        "catDetails": [
          {
            "cId": null,
            "typeCat": null,
            "title": "App1",
            "subCategory": null,
            "description": "App1 desc"
          },
          {
            "cId": null,
            "typeCat": null,
            "title": "App2",
            "subCategory": null,
            "description": "App2 desc"
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help me out on the solution and the reason to get these abnormalities. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **1)** You refer to *"different queries"* but show only a `select *`. **2)** You append to an uninitialised `result` instead of `res`  in your second code example, suggesting the code attached is not the actual code causing the problem you need help with. **3)** There's no sample data, example of a valid response, examples of failed/invalid/unexpected responses. **4)** You're asking for a reason why you *"get these errors"* without showing specific error messages. Do you think you could try and clarify the question a bit, show some specific examples and what you consider anomaly, the error?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited my question, added the responses for two resolver data that are interchanging.

Comment: These examples don't really help expand the context of your question. I understand your problem is that sometimes, the results are *not properly fetched* and you're getting `null` values instead of something you know for sure is in the database. Can you show an example of a query and one valid response it gets one time, then invalid response it gets another time? An example of this happening: *"In few random cases the data are not properly fetched and provided with some null values sometimes."*

Comment: Queries for fetching app and category details :
`query{
  FetchAppDetails{
    statusMsg
    appDetails{
      aId
      title
      typeApp
      subTitle
      description
    }
  }
}
query{
  FetchCatDetails{
    statusMsg
    appDetails{
      cId
      title
      typeCat
      subCategory
      description
    }
  }
}`

Comment: And for the proper response for app details:
`"aId": 11,
"typeApp": "Mobile",
"title": "App1",
"subTitle": "AppSub1",
"description": "App1 desc"`
category details:
`"cId": 101,
"typeCat": "Event",
"title": "Category1",
"subCategory": "CatSub1",
"description": "Category1 desc"`